# Issue on opening a page with serenity/cucumber

Tags: cucumber-java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I'm trying to open a page in the StepDefinition class by calling the open() method of the PageObject class.
The problem is that after this method is called it doesn't go to the instructions after:

```
homeSteps.openPage();
//the following instructions are not called
createOrganizations();
```

Can you help me please to resolve this issue?

Comment: could you please provide more information? what are the next instructions, what does happen, etc?

Comment: Also afaik the open() method is a Serenity method, so you might want to try any help channels they have.